# preg_match_all for numbers in certain parts of string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

```
Babylon 5 Season 4 Episode 13 Rumors Bargains and Lies 45
```

how i can extract numbers that comes after Season and the numbers that comes only after episode not any number after that. in the above example. i would want only 4 and 13 numbers using php using preg_match thanks in advance

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/u7bAYr/1

Comment: $g4 = preg_match_all('(?<=Season\s|Episode\s)\d+', $title1, $g);  checkout is this all right . its giving error that \ isnt unknow modifier

Comment: How would you extract the number in `don't care 42`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$str = 'Babylon 5 Season 4 Episode 13 Rumors Bargains and Lies 45';

if (preg_match_all("/(Season|Episode) (\d.)/", $str, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches);
}
```

And it will output:

```
   array (size=3)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'Season 4 ' (length=9)
          1 => string 'Episode 13' (length=10)
      1 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'Season' (length=6)
          1 => string 'Episode' (length=7)
      2 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string '4 ' (length=2)
          1 => string '13' (length=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have your `Season` and `Episode` values in an array `m`:

```
preg_match_all('/.*Season\s+(?<season>\d+)\s+Episode\s+(?<episode>\d+)/', $str, $m);

print 'Season: ' . $m['season'][0] . "\n";
print 'Episode: ' . $m['episode'][0] . "\n";
```

Comment: How I can get by '1d 2h 40m', '2h 40m', '1d 2h'?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex look behind to capture numbers.

```
(?<=Season)\s*?\d+|(?<=Episode)\s*?\d+
```

It should capture 4 and 13.

See https://regex101.com/r/JVOUOw/2